# Matching moments implies matching densities?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with matching moments (ie: $\mu_X^i = \mu_Y^i (\forall i \in \mathbb{Z}^+)$ then are the density functions of $X$ and $Y$ identical (almost everywhere)?

Idea: I'm thinking that this is true since their generating functions may be reconstructed via the information given by the moments whence they must be identical?

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_%28mathematics%29

> For a bounded distribution of mass or probability, the collection of
>   all the moments (of all orders, from 0 to ∞) uniquely determines the
>   distribution.

Comment: For a _bounded_ distribution it does, and also for some unbounded distributions.

Comment: A more relevant link might be to the so called [moment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem).